# Character constant too long for its type

Tags: c, variables

Code:

```
char menu_list[] = {'Boiled egg', 'Corn flakes', 'Gobi 65', 'Chicken 65', 'Basandi'};
```

Am a new to c programming i just wanted to make an array of string, but am getting an waring as below. can anyone please tell me why its happening. Its a c program.

```
main_menu.c:226: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type
main_menu.c:226:36: warning: character constant too long for its type
```

Comment: That's an array of char. Try `char *menu_list[]` which is an array of pointer to char, aka an array of "string".

Comment: To add to what Thomas said, single quotes have a different meaning than double quotes.

Comment: I'm wondering if this wasn't in that tutorial (hint: it probably was)... `'foo'` is not the same as `"foo"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Its been a valuable comment and advice.

Comment: `'Boiled egg'` is a multi-character character constant. It has an implementation-defined value. Such constants are very rarely useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use double quotes for string lliteral, and you are wrongly declaring the array.

Perhaps you are looking for thiss.

```
char *menu_list[] = {"Boiled egg", "Corn flakes", "Gobi 65", "Chicken 65", "Basandi"};
```

Comment: The 2D array with all dimensions unspecified won't compile.

Comment: @H2CO3 edited......out of java habits...that doesn't require that and I'm used to it...sorry

Answer (score 1):

Change `char menu_list[]` to `char * menu_list[]`  and use `"Boiled egg"` rather than `'Boiled egg'`.

The final code should look like

```
char *menu_list[] = {"Boiled egg", "Corn flakes"};
```